# How to fade-in image transition on page load, using flutter?

Tags: flutter

I don't believe I am asking such a simple question.

I try to change opacity in `initState()` but it does not have an effect.

How do I trigger `setState` if I don't use a button?

Here is the [DARTPAD](https://dartpad.dev/3797b8f408aabda92950008f8ccacfa0?null_safety=true).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: LogoFade(),
    );
  }
}

class LogoFade extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => LogoFadeState();
}

class LogoFadeState extends State<LogoFade> {
  double opacityLevel = 0.0;

  void changeOpacity() {
    setState(() => opacityLevel = 1.0);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    changeOpacity();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// changeOpacity();
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        AnimatedOpacity(
          opacity: opacityLevel,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 6),
          child: FlutterLogo(
            size: 200,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**I just want a simple **FadeIn** effect like Animate.css library.** Like we make in web with the example below.

```css
.fade-in-image {
  animation: fadeIn 6s;

}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}
```

```html
<div class="fade-in-image">
   <img src="https://www.innodeed.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/flutter-logo.png">
</div>
```

Comment: I think transitions on page loads have very common usage.

Answer (score 0):

In flutter app life cycle `intiState()` called before the `Widget build(BuildContext context)` called.So technically your `opacity` varriable always initialize with 1.You can use `FutureDelay` to see the effect of this animation.

```
void changeOpacity() async{
await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000));
setState(() => opacityLevel = 1.0);
}

 @override
 void initState() {
 changeOpacity();
 super.initState();
}
```